# assigning tuple to an int variable and printing the variable

Tags: c, variable-assignment, comma-operator

I tried assigning a tuple to an `int` variable. Here is my code. `i = (12, 45, 58, -1, 90, 100);` When I print `i`, it shows the value of `100`. How does tuple work in C language ?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't.  C isn't Python.  There are no tuples in C. In C, `(1, 2, 3)` is just a parenthesized sequence of comma operations, which evaluate to their second argument, so it is equivalent to `3`.  In you example, your "tuple" simply evaluates to `100`.

Comment: Maybe you require [arrays](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays_and_strings) in c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side expression is an expression with the comma operator

```
i = (12, 45, 58, -1, 90, 100);
```

Its value and the type is the value and the type of the last operand.

In fact the above statement is equivalent to

```
i = 100;
```

because other sub-expressions do not have a side effect.

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
> expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
> of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
> has its type and value.

Comment: Makes sense Vald

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, you can use `structure` as an alternative.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char name[10];
}TupleInfo;

int main()
{
    TupleInfo tuple1 = {1, 2, "Marty"};
    printf("%d %d %s\n", tuple1.num1, tuple1.num2, tuple1.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 Marty
```

Note: If you want to work with the similar data type, then using an array might be more convenient.

To learn more about structure in C, please check the following resources:

- [C struct](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures)
- [Structures in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structures-c/)

Comment: it'll not be a tuple. tuple is for classes  where you can do `std::piecewise_construct` in pair on tuple. https://github.com/alexeyneu/BlockZero/blob/65b98a062bc5649c7b3cb1198d6cdbe4f5a597a8/connection/x.cpp#L511

Comment: c++ has structures also